# Is there any way I can convert any MS Document to PDF using LibreOffice SDK in java?

Tags: java, pdf, libreoffice

I want to write the code which will take input as ms document and convert it into PDF. I want to use LibraOffice SDK for conversion, but not able to find the related things. Is it possible to do? If yes, can you give me some pointers?

Comment: I'd be happy if I get to know what's wrong in this question when down voting!

Answer (score 2):

LibreOffice has native PDF "save as" capability, and of course you can exploit this feature from SDK.
I use it in my ASP.NET VC#, with I post here. I guess java will not be very different.

Once you have worked on your xDocument (both Calc or Write) you save them as PDF in this way:

```
            XStorable xStorable = (XStorable)xDocument;
            PropertyValue[] storeProps = new PropertyValue[3];
            storeProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
            storeProps[0].Name = "FilterName";
            storeProps[0].Value = new uno.Any("writer_pdf_Export");
            storeProps[1] = new PropertyValue();
            storeProps[1].Name = "Overwrite";
            storeProps[1].Value = new uno.Any(true);
            storeProps[2] = new PropertyValue();
            storeProps[2].Name = "SelectPdfVersion";
            storeProps[2].Value = new uno.Any(1);

            xStorable.storeToURL("file:///" + outFile, storeProps);
            xDocument.dispose();
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know much about LibreOffice SDK, but this is certainly doable with iText (http://developers.itextpdf.com/apis). It's an easy to use API.

I have also had good results from Apache FOP. That said, beware there, as it is much slower and can be a memory hog as it loads the entire document into memory.

Comment: I want to use which is opensource.

Comment: iText is AGPL.  [Here's some info on that](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107883/agpl-what-you-can-do-and-what-you-cant)

Comment: Apache FOP is licensed under Apache 2 license, both of those are open source